# Sql friends datatable query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hey guys, I am really messing up with this. I tried this but it failed. I have following three tables with user polard searched 2 times at different days, with increased friends in second search in table b. I just need to build the query which will give me the two newly added friends (wont be present in end of list of second search). In table c there will be 20 friends of polard displayed with usid 1 and then 22 friends with usid 2 means total  records will be 42.

```
table a               
uid  name
1     karos
2     polard

table b                              
usid  umid name    friends
1      2  polard    20
2      2  polard    22

table c 
usrid   usid  name   friends
 1       1    hansy  10
 2       1    boje   23
 .       .     .      .
 .       .     .      .
```

Your help will be geatly appreciated.
 Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT usrid 
FROM c 
WHERE usid = 2 
AND usrid NOT IN (SELECT usrid FROM c WHERE usid = 1)
```

If you want both the usid values to be dynamic as well, assuming that you need to do for the latest usid for polard, it might be something like

```
SELECT usrid 
FROM c 
WHERE usid = 
       SELECT MAX (usid) FROM b WHERE name = 'polard') 
AND usid NOT IN 
      (SELECT usrid FROM c WHERE usid = 
           SELECT MAX (usid) - 1 FROM b WHERE name = 'polard'))
```

This is assuming that the usid values are integer incrementing values specific for each umid in table b.

If they arent, then it will be a bit more complicated as you need to do an Order by and get the 2nd to last umid value

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery using NOT IN

following the example in  http://www.dba-oracle.com/sql/t_subquery_not_in_exists.htm, you can say, give me all friends of user id 2, NOT in (friends of user id 1)